# Take a string and return a new string with each characters and their occurence

Tags: python, string

How would you create a Python function that takes a string and returns a new string that contains the characters of the given string once each (without repetitions), in the same order, and with their number of repetitions. For example, if the given string is `"aaaabbbbccddde"`, the result would be `"a4b4c2d3e1"`.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: To clarify, as this unclear question already received answers who interpret it in two different ways:  what would be the expected output for 'aba'? 'a2b1' or 'a1b1a1'?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

s = "aaaabbbbccddde"

out = "".join(f"{v}{sum(1 for _ in g)}" for v, g in groupby(s))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
a4b4c2d3e1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the `set` and append the count along with it. So, there might be a chance of changing the order of values. So you can do this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
result = ''.join(i+str(s.count(i)) for i in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)))
```

Execution,

```
In [1]: s = 'aaaabbbbccddde'

In [2]: ''.join(i+str(s.count(i)) for i in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)))
Out[2]: 'a4b4c2d3e1'
```

Answer (score -1):

One class in the Python standard library is the [Counter class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (`from collections import Counter`). This counts the occurrences of any character into a dict-like. For your use case, it can be used like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

string = "aaaabbbbccddde"
counter = Counter(string)

new_string = “”

# loops over each letter
for letter in counter.keys():
    # adds the letter and the number of occurences to new_string
    new_string += letter + counter[letter]
```